# Frequency encoding - should I make dummy columns?

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning

I am busy prepping data to train a machine learning model. Many of the features can work well with one-hot encoding. For one feature, the frequency is related to the target variable. I have been reading up a bit about frequency encoding and everything I find has to do with replacing the category with the frequency, like so:

```
CategoryName
------------
Blue
Blue
Blue
Yellow
Yellow
Red
```

Turning into:

```
CategoryName
------------
3
3
3
2
2
1
```

If I had done one-hot, I would have had:

```
Blue   Yellow   Red
1      0        0
1      0        0
1      0        0
0      1        0
0      1        0
0      0        0
```

All of the above may be related to a single line in the data I want to join it to, so I was wondering if this would be useful:

```
Blue   Yellow   Red
3      2        1
```

If so, is there a simple way to do it, like `get_dummies()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `value_counts` as mapping dict:

```
>>> df['CategoryName'].replace(df.value_counts())
0    3
1    3
2    3
3    2
4    2
5    1
Name: CategoryName, dtype: int64
```

**Note**: take care if some values have the same frequency like `['Blue', 'Blue', 'Yellow', 'Yellow', 'Red']`, the result will be `[2, 2, 2, 2, 1]`

**Update**

To get only one line:

```
>>> df.value_counts().to_frame().T
  Blue Yellow Red
0    3      2   1
```

**Update 2**

> The target variable can be influenced by how many applications the orchard has had, not just whether it had an application or not.

It makes sense so in this case, all fertilizers should be process as separated variables:

```
>>> df
  Orchad Fertilizer
0      A         F1
1      A         F1
2      A         F1
3      A         F1
4      A         F2
5      A         F2
6      B         F1
7      B         F1
8      B         F1
9      B         F3

>>> pd.crosstab(df['Orchad'], df['Fertilizer'])
Fertilizer  F1  F2  F3
Orchad                
A            4   2   0
B            3   0   1

# Use normalize={'all'|'index'|'columns'} or StandardScaler
>>> pd.crosstab(df['Orchad'], df['Fertilizer'], normalize='columns')
Fertilizer        F1   F2   F3
Orchad                        
A           0.571429  1.0  0.0
B           0.428571  0.0  1.0
```

Comment: Thanks. I am comfortable getting the output you have above. However, I want to make this relate to a single line. It is for a model regarding orchard outputs. For example: I have orchard A and it has one of three soil types. For this one-hot works well. Orchard A may have had four applications of 'fertilizer 1', two applications of 'fertilizer 2', and no applications of 'fertilizer 3'. Orchart B on the other hand may have had three applications of 'fertilizer 1', no applications of 'fertilizer 2'

Comment: Try `df.value_counts().rename_axis(None).to_frame().T`. However, I don't know how you can use this result in your ML model?

Comment: Thanks @Corralien, I don't know either. That is what I am trying to find out. I might go ahead and see if I get good results.

Comment: So why don't you use only one-hot encoder?

Comment: The target variable can be influenced by how many applications the orchard has had, not just whether it had an application or not, which is what one-hot would give me. For example, an orchard that has had three applications of fertiliser may yield more fruit than an orchard that has had only one.

Comment: @opperman.eric. It makes sense. I updated my answer, can you check it please?

Answer (score 2):

With [pandas](/questions/tagged/pandas) you can use a self [`groupby.transform('size')`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html):

```
out = df.groupby('CategoryName')['CategoryName'].transform('size')
```

If you already calculated the dummies, just [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) their [`sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html):

```
dummies = pd.get_dummies(df['CategoryName'])
out = df['CategoryName'].map(dummies.sum())
```

Output:

```
0    3
1    3
2    3
3    2
4    2
5    1
Name: CategoryName, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Thanx for this mozway. if all of the above relates to a single line, would putting the counts into dummy columns work when training the model?

Comment: @opperman.eric I can't say for sure, it might depend on your training model, I would assume this is not such a good idea as it might bias it creating artificial weights

Comment: Noted. Considering the example I posted in the comments to Corralien's answer, how would you recommend I approach it? In that example, is bias not what I would be after?